# Python: UDP socket's recvfrom returning localhost or external IP

Tags: python, sockets

I have a client program that uses two UDP sockets, one for listening and the other for writing.

```
OUT_SOCKET = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) # write-only UDP
IN_SOCKET = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) # read-only UDP
```

I run the program on localhost on two different ports and send messages to each other.

```
OUT_SOCKET.sendto(some_msg, (ip, port))
```

And I read the message like this.

```
msg, addr = IN_SOCKET.recvfrom(MAX_MSG_SIZE)
```

The problem is, when I specify 127.0.0.1 for the ip (for sending `some_msg`), on the receiving client, the `addr` is set to 127.0.0.1. But when I specify ip to 192.168.X.X (my external IP address) from sending client, the receiving client's `addr` is set to 192.168.X.X.

I expect `addr` to be consistent no matter how `ip` is set. Does `recvfrom` behave differently depending on how the sender specifies the ip address?

How does recvfrom extract remote address? What's causing `recvfrom` to behave differently?

Comment: I might have missed something here, but its the sender's IP address. When the client sends to `192.168.X.X`, it is sending on the machine's external IP interface so that's what you'd expect. `127.0.0.1` shouldn't make it into the external network because it has no meaning there.

Comment: @tdelaney Well, both sender and receiver are on my local machine. So I thought it would make sense for addr to be either 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.X.X because the sender is my machine. But it's weird that sometimes it's 127.0.0.1 and sometimes it's 192.168.X.X. I was wondering what would cause the inconsistency.

Comment: They are two different interfaces that don't route to each other so they act like two separate computers. Suppose you plugged in another network `10.0.X.X` that was separate from the 192 network. You'd want the `10.0.X.X` address sent to, say, `10.0.0.99` or else it wouldn't know how to send things back to you.

Comment: So if A is sending something to B at 192.168.X.X, A is sending the message from 192.168.X.X because B is at external interface? And vice versa for localhost case?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. Because you didn't `bind` to one interface, B will get datagrams from all of the interfaces. If A sends on `192.168.X.X`, B's external interface gets the datagram. Suppose A had bound only to `127.0.0.1` ... if B returned a dgram on `192.168.X.X`, A wouldn't receive it. It makes more sense when you are talking on multiple computers, but the rules are the same regardless.

Answer (score 1):

The address returned from `recvfrom` is specifically the source IP address in the packet received.  When you send a UDP packet using `sendto`, the IP stack will choose the appropriate interface to send the packet from.  `recvfrom` is not behaving differently, `sendto` choose the source network interface based on IP routing rules.

In your case, you have two network interfaces -- one that is listening for packets with a destination address of `127.0.0.1` and another that is listening on `192.168.x.y`.  When you send a packet using `sendto`, it has to originate from a network interface that can route to the destination address.

When you send a packet to `127.0.0.1`, it will originate from the loopback address (e.g., `127.0.0.1`).  When you send a packet to `192.168.x.y`, it will originate from the second network interface.  In both cases, the peer IP address returned from `recvfrom` identifies the sending network interface.

Comment: Its the source address of the sender so you know who sent it to you.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The doc says: The return value is a pair (string, address) where string is a string representing the data received and address is the address of the socket sending the data.

Comment: @mark - no idea what I was thinking when I wrote my original answer.  I rewrote the answer ;)